# align markup to bottom of page

Tags: lilypond

I have some music where I put the stanzas below:

```
\version "2.20.0"

#(set! paper-alist (cons '("size8" . (cons (* 8 cm) (* 8 cm))) paper-alist))

\paper {
  #(set-paper-size "size8")
  first-page-number = 1
  print-page-number = ##t
  print-first-page-number = ##t
  oddFooterMarkup = \oddHeaderMarkup
  evenFooterMarkup = \evenHeaderMarkup
  oddHeaderMarkup = \markup \empty-markup
  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup \empty-markup
}

\bookpart { 
  \score {
    { c'1 d'2 }
    \layout { indent = #0 }
  }
  \markup {
    \column {
      \line { some stanza text }
      \line { that should be }
      \line { aligned to the }
      \line { bottom of the page }
    }
  }
}
```

That markup is put right below the music by default:

[image]

**But I want it to be aligned to the bottom of the page** (above the footer), like this:

[image]

**Is that possible, and if yes, how?**

I know I can add `\vspace` to move it further below, but I want it ALIGNED to the bottom, so that it works for all markups and not just for specific ones where I fiddled around and found good numbers for `\vspace`.